# How to apply corner radius to specific corners for a CAShapeLayer, not UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I am drawing a bar chart and I want each bar to have a corner radius just on top.

Here is my code to draw a bar:

```
let barLayer = CAShapeLayer()
barLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth, height: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - yPos)

let path =  UIBezierPath(roundedRect: barLayer.frame, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
barLayer.path = path.cgPath
barLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
mainLayer.addSublayer(barLayer)
```

When applying this to an `UIView` I would just add another line:

```
myView.layer.mask = barLayer
```

But working with `CAShapeLayer` got me a little confused. How can I add the corner radius to it ?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

edit2: trying to use two layers:

```
let cornerRadiusLayer = CAShapeLayer()
cornerRadiusLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth, height: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - yPos)
let path =  UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cornerRadiusLayer.frame, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
cornerRadiusLayer.path = path.cgPath

let barLayer = CALayer()
barLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth, height: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - yPos)
barLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
barLayer.mask = cornerRadiusLayer
mainLayer.addSublayer(barLayer)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the bar from the chart to have a corner radius on top of it, but my bar is a CAShapeLayer

Comment: What does it look like at the moment?

Comment: Straight rectangle, no corner radius anywhere.

Comment: I think you need to use two layers: one layer to draw the rectangle, another one to mask that first layer with cornerRadius: `rectangleLayer.mask = cornerRadiusLayer`and then add your rectangleLayer to your main layer

Comment: @Ocunidee: I tried that, see my updated question with code, for some reason the bars don't appear anymore. I tried setting the color for the cornerRadiusLayer too, but they don't appear anymore, so I am doing something wrong.

Comment: see my answer below ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the layer's `maskedCorners` property?

```
let barLayer = CAShapeLayer()
barLayer.frame = // some frame
barLayer.masksToBounds = true

barLayer.cornerRadius = // some corner radius
barLayer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.colors = // some colors
gradient.frame = barLayer.bounds

barLayer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Results in:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Please add to CALyer Instance.

```
barLayer.masksToBounds  = true
```

Comment: Please add same in my View,  myView.layer.masksToBounds  = true

Comment: No change, still same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't see the rounded corners because you set `barLayer.backgroundColor`. Try using `barLayer.fillColor` instead.

Comment: That will not show the color at all from what I can see. I can see the corners if I use .cornerRaiuds property of the layer for all corners

Comment: Just to make sure: So it will "work" if you replace the 'barLayer.path = path.cgPath' with 'barLayer.cornerRadius = 5' and dosen't change anything else?

Comment: From iOS11 you can easily do that in a few lines of code by using `layer.maskedCorners`

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented a bit in a Playground to reproduce your case and basically this code works:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 560, height: 760))

let mainLayer = CALayer()
mainLayer.frame = view.frame
view.layer.addSublayer(mainLayer)

let cornerRadiusLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let rect = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100)
let cornerRadiusPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
cornerRadiusLayer.path = cornerRadiusPath.cgPath

let barLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
barLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath
barLayer.mask = cornerRadiusLayer
barLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor


mainLayer.addSublayer(barLayer)
```

You don't need to give frames to your layers, the UIBezierPath is enough and you should use the fillColor instead of the backgroundColor.
Also, use a CAShapeLayer for your BarLayer.

This is the result of the above code:

[image]

Comment: How is your mainLayer defined?

Comment: private let mainLayer: CALayer = CALayer()

Answer (score 0):

It's super easy with custom view like bellow

```
@IBDesignable class VerticalGradientView: VariableSeparateCornerView {
    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = UIColor.green {
        didSet {
           setGradient()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = UIColor.yellow {
        didSet {
            setGradient()
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setGradient()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initView()
    }

    private func initView() {
        self.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 20)
    }

    private func setGradient() {
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    }
}

@IBDesignable class VariableSeparateCornerView: UIView {

    private var corners: UIRectCorner = [.allCorners]
    private var radius: CGFloat = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.refreshCorners()
    }

    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        self.corners = corners
        self.radius = radius
        self.refreshCorners()
    }

    private func refreshCorners() {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

**Use:**
Just drage `UIView` and set custom class to `VerticalGradientView`
[image]